# How to post an array successfully to Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is a snapshot of my JSON of Players:

[image]

Below is the code used to select the players on the client side:

```
$scope.history=[];
$scope.picked = [];

 $scope.buy = function(player) {
        //remove if already added locally
        var index = $scope.history.indexOf(player);
        var index2 = $scope.picked.indexOf(player.id);
        if(index>=0 || index2>=0 ){
            $scope.history.splice(index,1);
            $scope.picked.splice(index2,1);
            return;
        }
 
        //max 11 allowed
        if($scope.history.length>=10 || $scope.picked.length>=10){
            alert('max 10 players allowed');
            return;
        }
        //to make sure moeny doesn't go below $10,000,000
        if($scope.total<0){
            alert('Oops! You have run out of cash');
            return;
        }
 
        var selected = $scope.history.reduce(function(a,b){
            a[b.position] = (a[b.position] || 0) + 1;
            return a;
        }, {}) || {};
 
        if(!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position]<4 && 
            $scope.total>0){
            $scope.history.push(player);
            $scope.picked.push(player.id);
               
        }else{
            alert('You can add only four players per position');
             
        }
      };
```

The code produces the below selected players (as an example):

```
[
0: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 1, …}
1: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 2, …}
2: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 3, …}
3: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 4, …}
4: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 5, …}
5: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 6, …}
6: {Team: "AC Izzue", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 7, …}
7: {Team: "After Hours FC", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 16, …}
8: {Team: "Alaye FC", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id: 27, …}
9: {Team: "Alaye FC", assists: 0, cost: "5m", goals: 0, id 26}
]
```

Each time i try to `push` or `set` this array of selected players into my firebase database i get the error below  :

> Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains an invalid key ($id) in property 'users.UhIBZDBaLcTcesdRiJ9u7xYv9bd2.picked.0'. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Is it possible to post the array at a user nade on the firebase successfully or does the array have to change?

Comment: Can you share the exact code used to build the Array and to push to the database? Note that what you show in you question is not a valid [JavaScript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have made edits to the question to reflect the code. Thank you. I am quite new to Firebase

Comment: I'm not sure to find, in your code snippet, the code used to build the Array and to push to the database

Comment: @RenaudTarnec the array is initially empty i.e $scope.history and then the array gets filled using the $scope.buy function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to understand the code of your question, since it is dependent of several other variables and values.

If you want to get, in your Firebase Realtime Database, what you show in the screenshot attached to your question, you need to pass an Array of objects to the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method, as follows:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('players')
    .set([
      { Team: 'AC Izzue', assists: 0, cost: '5m', goals: 0, id: 1 },
      { Team: 'AC Izzue', assists: 0, cost: '5m', goals: 0, id: 2 },
    ]);
```

---

If you use the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) method, which seems to be the case from the error you are receiving, you will create a new child location with an auto-generated key and end with something like:

```
   "players" : {
    "-MESdJeoccFv8mc5Qhhd" : [ {  // <=== auto-generated key
      "Team" : "AC Izzue",
      "assists" : 0,
      "cost" : "5m",
      "goals" : 0,
      "id" : 1
    }, {
      "Team" : "AC Izzue",
      "assists" : 0,
      "cost" : "5m",
      "goals" : 0,
      "id" : 2
    } ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the issue is instead setting the array as you've posted above, it puts an $id before each player object and that is what returns the error. the player JSON is fixed so i guess i will have to find away to use push to get a key that doesn't return an error